# How to replace a button text with customized text using Selenium Python (MacOS)?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to basically do a temporary edit to a webpage (like how people do it using inspect element) but have it done automatically using selenium. For example this is an image from google.ca :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSXi9.jpg

I simply want to change the text of "Gmail" and "Images" into whatever I want.

I only have this so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/--------/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get("https://google.ca/")
x = browser.find_element_by_id('Gmail')
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: but why though?

Comment: @SuperStew I just want it so that when the browser is ran, it has my custom text in it.

Comment: for what purpose though?

Comment: I don't think you can set attributes with selenium unfortunately.

Comment: @SuperStew Do you know any libraries that support this by any chance?

Comment: no not really..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the text of a *WebElement* within a webpage e.g. the [LINK_TEXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) **Gmail** on [Google Home Page](https://www.google.ca/) with a customized text e.g. **Atomization** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.ca/')
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Gmail")))
  driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('div#viewport a').innerText = 'Atomization'")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: change_innerText]

Comment: So this does work, However, it doesnt change the gmail. it changes the left side of the browser where it says "About" beside Store. I'm just gonna treat this as an answer though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  document.querySelector('button').innerText = 'Hi There'
""")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't even give an error.


`browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/-------/Downloads/chromedriver')

browser.get("https://google.ca/")

browser.execute_script("""
  document.querySelector('button').innerText = 'Hi There'
""")`